# MPMoviePlayer goes black on Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming, mpmovieplayer

I am playing a Live Streaming Video in my application using the MPMoviePlayerController. While playing, the screen sometimes goes into black , but I am able to hear the Audio. Why so ? . I tried to get the Notification when the screen goes black, but I am unlucky.

Can anyone tell me why the screen goes black for live streaming ?
How to get notified when MPMoviePlayer goes black ?

Please help me !!

Comment: Have you sorted out this issue?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyKanagaraj. I assume that this problem sometimes occur mainly because of the data provider. It is fact that , if you have low bandwidth audio get streamed first over video. For me , this issue is solved by making some changes in the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTTP Live Streaming overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) has this to say.

> The data rate that a content provider chooses for a stream is most
>   influenced by the target client platform and the expected network
>   topology. The streaming protocol itself places no limitations on the
>   data rates that can be used. The current implementation has been
>   tested using audio-video streams with data rates as low as 64 Kbps and
>   as high as 3 Mbps to iPhone. Audio-only streams at 64 Kbps are
>   recommended as alternates for delivery over slow cellular connections.

Basically if the network is too slow to stream the video, then an audio-only mode will be used. I can't find a way to get notifications for alternate changes with MPMoviePlayerController. However you can register for the `MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification` which will allow you to know whether audio/video/both are available (through the `movieMediaTypes` property).

```
enum {
   MPMovieMediaTypeMaskNone  = 0,
   MPMovieMediaTypeMaskVideo = 1 << 0,
   MPMovieMediaTypeMaskAudio = 1 << 1
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieMediaTypeMask;
```

I'm not completely sure it will notify you when the streaming switches to audio only but you can always try.

Comment: Yeah. I have added the MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification too. Still the screen goes blank and no notifications is being called. Actually I thought of pausing the streaming video when the screen goes black. Any lead please ??